# Finding the geodesic equations on $S^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> The metric on $S^2$ is given as $\bar{g} = ds^2 = d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta d\phi^2$ where $x^1 = \theta$ and $x^2 = \phi$. The only non-zero components of the Christoffel symbols are $\Gamma^{\ 1}_{ \ 2 \ 2}$ and $$\Gamma^{\ 2}_{ \ 2 \ 1} =  \Gamma^{\ 2}_{ \ 1 \ 2} =  \cot\theta$$
>
> Write down the geodesic equations for the co-ordinates $\theta(t)$ and $\phi(t$)

I know that in local co-ordinates on any smooth manifold $M$ the geodesic equation is given by $$\frac{d^2x^a}{dt^2} +  \Gamma^{\ a}_{ \ b \ c}\frac{dx^b}{dt}\frac{dx^c}{dt} = 0$$

on $S^2$ then substituting for $x^1$ and $x^2$ in local co-ordinates we get $$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} -\sin\theta\cos\theta \left(\frac{d\phi}{dt}\right) + \frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2} + 2\cot\theta \frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{d\phi}{dt} = 0$$

rearranging for $\frac{d^2\theta}{dt}$ we get

$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} =\sin\theta\cos\theta \left(\frac{d\phi}{dt}\right) - \frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2} - 2\cot\theta \frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{d\phi}{dt} $$

and similarly we can rearrange and solve for $\frac{d^2\phi}{dt}$. My question is, what exactly do the authors mean by "write down the geodesic equations for the co-ordinates $\theta(t)$ and $\phi(t)$, do I need to solve the above differential equation and then obtain $\theta(t)$? If so how can I go about doing that, what's the best approach?

Comment: the index $a$ is not summed, hence you have the equations for $a=1$ getting $\ddot{\theta}=\ldots$ and for $a=2$ getting $\ddot{\phi}=\ldots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two geodesic equations, one for $x^1 = \theta$ and one for $x^2 = \phi$. 
Note that the Christoffel symbols should be $\Gamma_{22}^2 = -\sin\theta\cos\theta$ and $\Gamma_{12}^2=\Gamma_{21}^2=2\cot\theta$ (with a factor $2$). Substituting gives
$$
\begin{align*}
\theta''-\sin\theta\cos\theta \left(\phi'\right)^2&=0 \\
\phi'' + 2\cot\theta \theta'\phi' &=0. 
\end{align*}
$$
where ${}'$ is the derivative w.r.t. to $t$. First integrate the second equation $\frac{ \phi''}{\phi'}=-2\cot \theta \theta'$. This gives 
$$\phi'=\frac{c}{\sin^2 \theta}.$$
Recall the fact that geodesics have unit speed. In this example this is expressed by
$$ (\theta')^2 + \sin^2 \theta (\phi')^2 =1.$$
Substituting $\phi'$ gives
$$ \theta' = \sqrt{\frac{\sin^2 \theta -c^2}{\sin^2 \theta}}.$$
Dividing $d\phi$ by $d\theta$ gives us the separable differntial equation
$$ \frac{d\phi}{d\theta} = \frac{c}{\sin\theta\sqrt{\sin^2\theta -c^2}}. $$
Integrating this is not a picknick, but essentially, it will give you a not so recognisable parametrisation of the great circles. (An example of a similar calculation can be found [here](https://mathproblems123.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/geodesiceqn.pdf).)

This approach hereabove holds more general. The parametrisation here is a [Clairaut parametrisation](https://mathproblems123.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/geodesiceqn.pdf) i.e. the parametrisation is orthogonal $F=0$ and $E$ and $G$ only depend on one parameter (here $E_\phi = G_\phi=0$). If you have a Clairaut parametrisation, you can integrate one of the 2nd order geodesic equations in the fashion as we did hereabove, so you will get a 1st order equation. Or, even better, you just directly use the socalled Clairaut equations (the integrated forms), so that you don't need to redo the integration yourself.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you found  $\phi ' = \frac{c}{sin^2(\theta)}$?

Comment: I just took the integral of both sides of $\frac{\phi''}{\phi'} = -2 \cot\theta \theta'$. Note that $\cot \theta =\frac{ \cos\theta}{\sin \theta} $.  So we get $\ln|\phi'| = -2 \ln|\sin \theta| + C = \ln |c\csc^2\theta|$ (where $c = \ln C$).