# Showing a Geodesic Result

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

> Given the surface of the unit sphere with usual metric
>   $$\large ds^2 = d\theta^2 + \sin^2(\theta)\,d\phi^2$$
>   I have calculated the Euler-Lagrange equations
>   \begin{align*}\large
> \ddot{\theta} - \sin\theta\cos\theta\dot{\phi}^2 &= 0\\ \large
> \ddot{\phi} + 2\cot\theta\dot{\phi}\dot{\theta} &= 0
> \end{align*}
>   Giving the Christoffel symbol components as
>   \begin{align*}\large
> \Gamma^\theta_{\phi\phi} = -\sin\theta\cos\theta,\quad\Gamma^\theta_{\theta\theta} = \Gamma^\theta_{\theta\phi} &= 0\\ \large
> \Gamma^\phi_{\theta\phi} = \Gamma^\phi_{\phi\theta} = \cot\theta,\quad\Gamma^\phi_{\theta\theta} = \Gamma^\phi_{\phi\phi} &= 0
> \end{align*}

---

> Now there is the question to show that a line of constant $\phi$ is a geodesic.

How would one go about this, given what I have done so far?

Comment: There is a very small typo: $ds^s$ should be $ds^2$.

Comment: oh yes a double tap, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show that curves with constant $\phi$ satisfy the geodesic equations. Geometrically you are showing that the great circles are geodesics.

We substitute $\dot \phi=0$ in the two geodesic equations above. The second geodesic equation holds trivially; the first equation becomes $\ddot \theta =0$. Now, note that we can always reparametrise a (regular) curve such that it has constant speed $c$. For a curve on the sphere, this means that 
$$  (\dot\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta (\dot \phi)^2= c^2.$$
If we now substitute $\dot \phi=0$, we see that $\dot \theta$ is constant. It follows that $\ddot \theta=0$. Thus the two geodesic equations are satisfied, so the curves with constant $\phi$ (with constant speed parametrisations) are geodesics.

Comment: @MRT Maybe you might find [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944206/finding-the-geodesic-equations-on-s2/2944262#2944262) also interesting.

Comment: okay so having that equation and getting $\ddot{\theta} = 0$ this answers the question? I'm still a little confused how this is related to $\phi$... If I think about having constant $\phi$ then that makes the first equation $\ddot{\theta} = 0$ as the first $\phi$ derivative would be zero for a constant and the second equation would just be $0=0$ with the first and second derivatives of $\phi$ are zero.

So I guess I don't see why $\ddot{\theta} = 0$ shows that constant $\phi$ is a geodesic.

Comment: I think I understand your confusion. I will reformulate my answer. Hopefully this will help a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking that could you just say$$\large \ddot{\theta}=0\Rightarrow\dot{\theta}=\text{const.}\Rightarrow\theta=a\lambda +\text{const.}$$ where $\theta$ is some linear result in the variable of differentiation $\lambda$. I’m just not sure how you found the reparametrisation

Comment: I used the fact that every regular curve can be reparametrised such that it has constant speed. I first used this reparametrision and then checked that $\ddot \theta =0$ holds. But indeed, so you can first solve $\ddot \theta=0$, and then use this to reparametrise the curve.